# Passing async values around object literal methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Unsure of how to pass the returned value of `getLocationsArray` outside of the getLocations method. How would this be done so `setMarkers` method can use it? Of course, im aware when calling methods or vars internally within an object literal i can use `APP.map.setMarkers` for example. Thanks.

```
 init: function(){
   ...ETC...
  APP.map.getLocations()
  APP.map.setMarkers(center, radius, map)
},

getLocations: function() {
  $.getJSON('data/json/locations.json', function(data) {
    var locations = data
    var getLocationsArray = $.map(locations, function(value, index) {
      return [value]
    })
    console.log(getLocationsArray)
    return getLocationsArray
  })
  console.log('getLocationsArray2', getLocationsArray2)
  return getLocationsArray2
},

setMarkers: function(center, radius, map) {
  **getLocationsArray**.forEach (function (hello) {
  ..ETC..
}
```

Comment: Can you make your question more clear and provide more code so one can understand what are you trying to do ?

Comment: `jQuery.getJSON` returns a promise - use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` will only deliver its result asynchronously, so you cannot use code that expects it to be available immediately. Instead use a callback system.

There is no use in returning a value inside the `$.getJSON` callback function: it will go to oblivion:

```
 return getLocationsArray // not useful.
```

You also refer to a variable `getLocationsArray2` that is never initialised.

Instead, you could pass a callback argument:

```
init: function(){
  // ...ETC...
  // Pass an (anonymous) callback function to `getLocations`, which
  // it will call when the result is available. Then you can call
  // `setMarkers` to process that result.
  APP.map.getLocations(function (getLocationsArray) {
      APP.map.setMarkers(getLocationsArray, center, radius, map);
  });
},

getLocations: function(callback) {
  $.getJSON('data/json/locations.json', function(data) {
    var locations = data
    var getLocationsArray = $.map(locations, function(value, index) {
      return [value]
    })
    // If a callback function was provided, then call it now and
    // pass it the result.
    if (callback) callback(getLocationsArray);
  })
},

setMarkers: function(getLocationsArray, center, radius, map) {
  // We get the locations array as an argument now, so it is straightforward
  // to process it:
  getLocationsArray.forEach (function (hello) {
     ///..ETC..
}
```

Comment: Asynchronicity! ...ffs. Thank you. Further reading for others (and me) on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron#answer-23667087